# Airflow: Logs are not showing in the UI

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

When I click on a task and then click on 'Log' button  it doesn't display anything

[image: example of the lack of logs]

However, I have edited the config file to store them somewhere specific.

`base_log_folder = /var/log/airflow`

and in the UI it specifically says that the log for that task is at `/var/log/airflow/solr-mentions-cleanups/run-solr-mentions-cleanups-1/2019-02-19T10:46:01.283247+00:00.log`, however in fact this log does not exist.

I expect that if I've specified a path in the config file then the logs should just go there. Not sure what other configurable things there are.

Comment: Is the task is running? You only have log when task is started to run.

Comment: Hey. It gets stuck in the 'scheduled for retry' state.

Comment: The log location in the TaskInstance details has been in-correct for a while, the actual path should be something like: `/var/log/airflow/solr-mentions-cleanups/run-solr-mentions-cleanups-1/2019-02-19T10:46:01.283247+00:00/1.log`. If you look in the browsers console do you see any errors reported?

Comment: Did you customize the `LOG_LEVEL` in settings.py by chance? If you set that to anything above `INFO` you will not get any logs on successful tasks (found out that one the hard way)

Comment: @bstorrie in my case LOG_LEVEL is INFO but the logs aren't showing!

Comment: What's your deployment method? If you're using Helm (and perhaps other deployments), the different workloads need the same secret key so they can talk to eachother (read: the webserver workload can grab logs from workers)

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/production-guide.html#webserver-secret-key

Comment: I suspect this could be a permission issue at the path `/var/log/airflow`. Have you verified the user has write privileges?